# Return only response body from Http interceptor while observing the response

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular application, I am using Http interceptor to append the JWT in each and every request. I also need to read some custom data from the response header which I am reading with the help of res.headers.get("authority") code. I have turned on {observe: 'response'} while sending the request to the server so that I can get the header information also.

I need to only return the response body to service/component from interceptor below is sample interceptor code snippet:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
//debugger
return next.handle(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    //return event.body;
    if (!localStorage.getItem("LoggedInUserRole"))
      this.authenticationService.setLoggedInUserRole(event.headers.get("authority"));
    return event;
    //debugger
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. You don't need to append the JWT in each and every request.

If, on your backend login route on a successful login, your server responds with the "Set-Cookie" header it will automatically set the JWT header in all subsequent requests, the client does not need to set a cookie.

e.g.

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; HttpOnly
```

To delete it when a user makes a logout request to the server, the server should respond with:

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=''; HttpOnly
```

This also has the benefit of making it http only which improves security.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: Hi @danday74 I need to send the JWT in that way only. Can you please help me with any way to only return the response body from interceptor not whole response. Thanks in advance.